# Configure a Windows based EC2 to route traffic through an IGW or NAT gw depending on route

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I have a use case where I need to create EC2 instances on demand with the following requirements:

- They need to have a public IP for users to connect to them directly (low latency environment and cannot use a load balancer because I need to know which machine I'm connecting to).
- I could need hundreds created at the same time in the same region (so I cannot use elastic IPs).
- They need to be able to connect to a public service that uses a whitelisting mechanism to allow access (so a NAT gateway comes to mind to be able to just have a single IP to whitelist).

Normally we use a NAT gateway to access the secure public service from our own private services but in this case, the EC2 instances are many and are created in a public subnet and have a public IP. I've tried adding a route in the route table associated with the subnets the instances are deployed on that points to the NAT gateway for the specific CIDR range of the service, but then I cannot access the instances anymore. I guess this is because of the public IP that cannot be NATed.

So, is there any way to configure the routing (probably at the OS level) so for the public service, calls go through the NAT gateway using the instance private IP (assuming the problem comes from it using the public IP to connect), and for any other calls, traffic goes through the Internet Gateway? Or maybe there is another solution? Or maybe I'm wrong about the reason why this configuration doesn't let me connect to the machine?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want to be using a proxy for outbound traffic, maybe something like squid?

Comment: I'm currently testing if I can do this using nginx as that's the one I know. I was looking for something more managed to avoid dealing with redundancy and availability

Comment: As far as I know, AWS has no proxy managed services